# Как из мобильного приложения определить язык устройства IOS/Android?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

Есть таск: для первого входа в мобильное приложение нужно определить **язык устройства** Android/IOS, с которого оно запущено. Само приложение написано с помощью платформы [Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/), используя стандартные веб-технологии Js, HTML, CSS. Ребят, может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой? 
Определение языка по гео положению не катит =(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13864359/get-phone-locale-settings-with-javascript попробуйте или http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673905/best-way-to-determine-users-locale-within-browser.

Comment: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-globalization/ вот вам плагин

Comment: Ребят, спасибо, но насколько я понимаю window.navigator отдает язык пользвательского интерфейса браузера, язык устройства же может отличаться.

Comment: @КонстантинАндрюшков, не может.(для Android)

Comment: Все таки navigator работает как надо, просто некоторым локалям устройства в приложении был переприсвоен другой язык. Спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Для iOS можно взять этот плагин (или любой другой для работы с NSUserDefaults) и получить массив строк по ключу "AppleLanguages". Первый элемент это текущий язык + локаль

https://github.com/protonet/cordova-plugin-nsuserdefaults-for-app-groups